# How to open a local file with a query string appended to it in the default browser?

Tags: mac, bash, terminal, shell, browser

I want to do something like this from a shell script:

```
$ open 'foo.html?foo=bar'
```

Sadly that fails, as it looks for a file named `foo.html?foo=bar` instead of `foo.html` before opening the browser:

```
The file /tmp/foo.html?foo=bar does not exist.
```

I noticed that `open` supports this for HTTP(S) URLs, though:

```
$ open 'https://mathiasbynens.be/demo/get?foo=bar'
```

So I tried to use a `file://` URL:

```
$ open 'file:///tmp/foo.html?foo=bar'
```

This doesn’t error (yay), but it still only opens `foo.html` in the browser, without the query string appended.

So, is this possible at all?

Comment: I suppose one could use AppleScript… But is there really no other way?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you can open the file with parameters directly - even if you specify the application with

`open -a "Safari" ...`.

Depending on what you want to accomplish you can start the built-in PHP web server with

`php -S localhost:8000`

and call your website with parameters like

`open "http://localhost:8000/foo.html/?foo=bar"`

I hope this helps.